# Is it possible to use linguijs in VUE application?

Tags: linguijs

Hello is there a way how to use this library in VUE.js application?

Thank you

I have tried it in VUE application. Followed manual part how to use it in javascript application.

Included @lingui/core and all cli libs from manual.

But I faced these issues:

- npm run extract > processeed only *.js files, *.vue files was ignored
- npm run serve > log is full of error like invalid or not found module and so on...

Comment: The Vue.js Lingui extractor is now available - https://lingui.dev/tutorials/extractor-vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long Vue SFC files are not a valid javascript, linguijs built-in extractor could not parse and extract messages from them. However, thanks to extendable lingui architecture, it's possible to write custom extractors which would transpile your `*.vue` files to the plain old-fashioned Javascript.

The concept is similar to loaders in webpack.

There is an ongoing work on creating Vue extractor as official LinguiJS package [here](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/pull/1578)

Regarding `npm run serve` it's most likely because you're trying to use `@lingui/macro` package where babel-plugin-macros is not enabled in your build pipeline.

Note that `vite-plugin-babel-macros` is not supporting `*.vue` files, that might be a root cause of the problem.

To learn more about integrating LinguiJS with Vue and Vite, you can refer to [this issue](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/issues/1567#issuecomment-1503761631) for more information and potential solutions.